# Subnetwork analysis on proteomics data

Tags: python, validation, network-programming

Background: I have proteomics data from seven samples (pvalue/ log-score of fold change), I want to analyze the data by network (interactome) analyses.

Question: I like to create an interactome of all the proteins from the data, and map the proteins to this network that have significant pvalue (compare to control), 
after that I like to create subnetwork(s); also like to add the pathways enrichments to the subnetwork(s).

Request: please suggest online or standalone tools (or algorithm) that fits my requirements.

Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

For creating network graphs to represent your protein-protein interactions, I would recommend taking a look at the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io) library. You can use it to pass in some nodes (proteins of interest) and edges (interactions) and generate a graph. I believe that it can also generate subnetworks of these graphs as well.